# Embedding a Twitter profile widget into a Facebook Page Tab-Application

Tags: facebook, twitter, tabs, widget

I have a page tab on a clients profile about a boxer that they sponser, sort of like a mini about-the-boxer website. One of the pages on this mini-site is a twitter profile widget feed, however the twitter API doesn't render when it is loaded into a FB iframe. I looked at the original url of the page (http://social.spiceboxwhisky.com/anthony/?page_id=10) and it works fine. Can anyone think of a way to get this twitter profile widget working?

Here's where you can view it on FB (must be 21+): https://www.facebook.com/spiceboxcanadianwhisky/app_253240968125508?app_data=page%3DTwitter

And on the host site: http://social.spiceboxwhisky.com/anthony/?page_id=10

Comment: There’s lots of errors in my firebug console when I visit your Facebook page tab, mostly about referenced JS files which could not be found … I’d suggest fixing that first.

Comment: I fixed the JS errors. What I just realized is that it works in Firefox, Safari & Opera but not in Chrome

Comment: Chrome’s developer tools show a number of message saying things like _“[blocked] The page at https;//social.spiceboxwhisky.com/anthony/ ran insecure content from http;//widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js.”_ – so these protocol mismatches are probably to blame. Try to link to your external resources in the form of `//example.com/foo` instead of `http://example.com/foo` – the first notation lets the browser decide about the protocol to use requesting these resources, depending on whether the parent document was requested via HTTP or HTTPS.